# Sharepoint list workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-workflow

I'm trying to create a Sharepoint Workflow (for SharePoint Online) in Visual Studio 2015 (Pro).

The workflow is for a specific document Library. But Visual Studio doesn't show me the available lists when trying to create the new workflow items.

Steps: `new item...` - `Workflow`
I select `List Workflow`, and then I can "Associate this workflow with the following lbiraries and lists".
Here is where it goes wrong, because the listboxes are empty.

[image: Empty lists]

Is there a property that I have to configure or a special link I have to make somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems impossible to leverage VS to create workflow for sharepoint online.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/989e3874-3756-4c33-bdb0-89a14a093c1c/visual-studio-2013-workflow-on-sharepoint-online-site-target-list-and-deployment-questions?forum=onlineservicessharepoint